# ASP.NET Web API : image upload error to cloudinary storage

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api2, cloudinary

I am creating a controller with CRUD functionalities but for the image, I am storing it in Cloudinary storage. My create controller works fine and is able to upload the image on cloudinary but on the update method in the controller throws an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'cloudinarydotnet.actions.imageuploadresult' to string

I am trying to put the DTO property to the model property to update the image.

`IPhotoService` interface:

```
using CloudinaryDotNet.Actions;

namespace TheRedChamber.Interfaces
{
    public interface IPhotoService
    {
        Task<ImageUploadResult> AddPhotoAsync(IFormFile file);
        Task<DeletionResult> DeletePhotoAsync(string publicId);
    } 
}
```

`PhotoService`:

```
using CloudinaryDotNet;
using CloudinaryDotNet.Actions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using TheRedChamber.Helpers;
using TheRedChamber.Interfaces;

namespace TheRedChamber.Services
{
    public class PhotoService : IPhotoService
    {
        private readonly Cloudinary _cloudinary;

        public PhotoService(IOptions<CloudinarySettings> config)
        {
            var account = new Account(
                config.Value.CloudName,
                config.Value.ApiKey,
                config.Value.ApiSecret);

            _cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);
        }

        public async Task<ImageUploadResult> AddPhotoAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var uploadResult = new ImageUploadResult();

            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using var stream = file.OpenReadStream();

                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams
                {
                    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, stream)
                };

                uploadResult = await _cloudinary.UploadAsync(uploadParams);
            }

            return uploadResult;  
        }

        public async Task<DeletionResult> DeletePhotoAsync(string publicUrl)
        {
            var publicId = publicUrl.Split('/').Last().Split('.')[0];
            var deletePrams = new DeletionParams(publicId);

            return await _cloudinary.DestroyAsync(deletePrams);
        }
    }
}
```

`MenuItem` model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TheRedChamber.Data
{
    public class MenuItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string SpecialTag { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; } 

        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public double Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`MenuItemUpdateDTO`:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TheRedChamber.Data.Dto
{
    public class MenuItemUpdateDTO
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string SpecialTag { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }

        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public double Price { get; set; }
        public IFormFile File { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Update method:

```
[HttpPut("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResponse>> UpdateMenuItem(int id, [FromForm] MenuItemUpdateDTO menuItemUpdateDTO)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var userMenuItem = _context.MenuItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (menuItemUpdateDTO is null || id != menuItemUpdateDTO.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            MenuItem menuItemFromDb = await _context.MenuItems.FindAsync(id);

            if (menuItemFromDb is null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            menuItemFromDb.Name = menuItemUpdateDTO.Name;
            menuItemFromDb.Price = menuItemUpdateDTO.Price;
            menuItemFromDb.Category = menuItemUpdateDTO.Category;
            menuItemFromDb.SpecialTag = menuItemUpdateDTO.SpecialTag;
            menuItemFromDb.Description = menuItemUpdateDTO.Description;

            if (menuItemUpdateDTO.File != null && menuItemUpdateDTO.File.Length > 0)
            {  
                await _photoService.DeletePhotoAsync(menuItemFromDb.Image);
                                                
                menuItemFromDb.Image =  await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(menuItemUpdateDTO.File);
            }

            _context.MenuItems.Update(menuItemFromDb);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            _response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent;

            return Ok(_response);
        }
        else
        {
            _response.IsSuccess = false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _response.IsSuccess = false;
        _response.ErrorMessages = new List<string>
                {
                    ex.Message
                };
    }

    return _response;
}
```

On the line

```
menuItemFromDb.Image =  await _photoService.AddPhotoAsync(menuItemUpdateDTO.File);
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'cloudinarydotnet.actions.imageuploadresult' to string

I am trying to delete the existing image that is already on the database and upload a new one, but I am not sure why I am getting this error.

I have tried looking through the web for answers and even on discord but found 1 person who has integrated cloudinary to his web api but he stopped responding after I sent pictures of my code.

I have also tried changing the `image` property in `Menuitem` class to `IFormFile`, but it caused another error. Although I was able to update it in the CREATE method but now unable to do so in my UPDATE method.

Comment: You can't use `IFormFile` in JSON DTOs (JSON is text-based, after all, and cannot contain raw binary content). It's only for `multipart/form-data` requests from `<form>` or `fetch()` - for a Web API you will need to accept _raw_ binary uploads, which need to be made separately - or have your users post an (accessible) URI to the binary/blob/etc in the JSON DTO.

Comment: Also, I see you're re-using Entity Framework entity types as DTOs - **don't do that**: it won't work: a DTO is not an entity. Entities have `[Required]` and `[Key]` members which render it impossible to use as JSON DTOs (e.g. how can a create-new-thing request supply a meaningful value for the `[Key]` value? etc etc) - and you open yourself up to overposting attacks.